# Nodejs (0.12.7) writeStream does not write more than one call to the write method

Tags: node.js, fs

**Context**: I'm working on a small nodejs tool (https://github.com/premkumaranand/csv-concat) to concat csv files that are primarily key-value pairs, and the tool allows one to add the path of the file to the key as a prefix before emitting the concatenated output to the resultant file.

**Premise**:

- testing this against nodejs 0.12.7, which is being used at my workplace.
- file read and write uses native nodejs fs

**Problem**: The concatenation works great when run using the [cli](https://github.com/premkumaranand/csv-concat/blob/master/csv-concat-cli.js) but not when running the tests with

```
grunt test
```

the test cases are [here](https://github.com/premkumaranand/csv-concat/blob/master/test/csv_concat_test.js). When running using test case, the resultant file has only the content from the first 'write' call. See below.

**How do I write into the file?**

```
    var outputStream = fs.createWriteStream(
        options.dest,
        {
            flags: 'a'
        });

    //...

    var records = csvFileParser.getRecords();

    records.forEach(function (recordIter) {
                outputStream.write(recordIter.join(options.delimiter) + '\n');
            });

    //...

    outputStream.end();
```

...as [here](https://github.com/premkumaranand/csv-concat/blob/master/csv-concat.js#L59).

**What have I tried so far?**

- Tried using the "open" event after createWriteStream
- And this:

  ```
  outputStream.on("end", function() {
                      outputStream.end();
                  });
  ```

But no luck. Any inputs welcome.

Comment: I don't know but when you run your code does it finish before you write those files? I mean is the write function async?

Comment: The write function is async indeed. That's why I tried the second point in my "What have I tried so far" list. For now, I ended up using a sync call as here: https://github.com/premkumaranand/csv-concat/pull/5. Not ideal because the code may suffer when the file being concatenated is bigger.